# Prove\Disprove: $\dim(U\cap W)=1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $W,U\subseteq V$ subspaces s.t $W\not \subseteq U$ 
>   $\dim(V)=5, \dim(W)=2, \dim(U)=4$
>
> Prove\Disprove: $\dim(U\cap W)=1$

So I started with \begin{align} & \dim(W+U)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U\cap W) \\[10pt]
\iff & \dim(W+U)=4+2-\dim(U\cap W)\end{align}

Now in the following steps I am not sure

Because $W,U\subseteq V$ subspaces $\dim(W+U)\leq \dim(V)=5$ So $1\leq \dim(U\cap W)$

What can I conclude from $W\not \subseteq U$ ? How should I continue?

Answer (score 2):

It remains to prove $\dim(U \cap W) \le 1$.
You already know $\dim(U \cap W) \le \dim(W) = 2$.
If you can show that $W \not\subseteq U$ implies $\dim(U \cap W) \ne 2$, then you are finished.

---

Proving the unproved claim above (via contrapositive): if $\dim(U \cap W) = 2$, then $U \cap W = W$ because $\dim(W)=2$. This implies $W = U \cap W \subseteq U$.

Comment: Can we say the $W\not \subseteq U\Rightarrow W\cap U\not\subseteq W$ and therefore $Dim(W\cap U)\leq Dim(W)=2$?

Comment: it is always the case that $W\cap U \subseteq W$, by definition

Answer (score 1):

From $\dim(W+U)\leq \dim(V)=5$ and using that $1\leq \dim(U\cap W)\leq\dim(W)=2$ we get two cases. If $\dim(U\cap W)=2=\dim(W)$, then $W\cap U=W$, as $W\cap U \subset W$, so $W\subset U$, which contradicts our initial assumption. So $\dim(U\cap W)=1$.